# Domain changes its TTL value frequently

Tags: dns, domain-name, ttl

I have been monitoring a few domains for my project work. Usually the TTL value in the DNS record for a domain is constant. But a certain domain shows change in its TTL values. Why would a domain change its TTL value frequently?

Comment: Which name server are you querying?

Comment: I am querying the authoritative name server of the domain under observation.